# React Native Firebase onAuthStateChanged returns user after signOut

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I'm struggling with signing out in my app. I'm using freshly installed managed Expo app with dev-client and **@react-natice-firebase/auth**, all in their current version. For the user state i'm using Recoil. Sign in works just fine, the problem occurs when signing out. Here is my **AuthProvider.ts**

```
import React, { FC, Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';

import auth, { FirebaseAuthTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { useSetRecoilState } from 'recoil';

import { firebaseUser } from '../../../state/user/atoms/firebaseUser';

export const AuthProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const setUser = useSetRecoilState(firebaseUser);
  const onAuthStateChanged = (user: FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null) => setUser(user);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);

    return subscriber;
  }, []);

  return <Fragment children={children} />;
};
```

And the function I use to sign out:

```
const logout = () => async () => await auth().signOut()

<MainButton action={logout()} label={'Logout'} />
```

After sign in the **onAuthStateChanged** listener returns **user object**, but after hitting 'Logout' button it returns the user object again instead of **null** and the interface doesn't update. After hitting it again, console returns an error:

**[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: [auth/no-current-user] No user currently signed in.]**

**onAuthStateChanged** is not called again, user state persists and the interface doesn't update.

User state is cleared after restarting the app and the sign in works just fine again. The behaviour is similar when switching users (eg. from anonymous to signed in).

Comment: How is the firebaseUser configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone will face the same problem in the future, so here's what was causing it. It wa Recoil, apparently the two libraries don't work well together, so I've rewritten it using context and works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In your useEffect, you need to actually call the 'unsubscribe' function provided by useAuthStateChanged.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);

    return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Comment: Check usage example in the official docs

https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage

It's done the way I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Along with googleOauth signout you also need to signout from firebase

```
const signOut = async () => {
try {
  await GoogleSignin.signOut(); //GoogleOAuth logout
  await auth().signOut();  //Firebase logout
  console.log('Sign out');
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
}};
```

Talking about unhandled promise rejection this occurs when you don't use try-catch block while calling funcitons using "await"